# @Singleton with static getInstance method

Tags: singleton, ejb

I have a question regarding ejb @Singleton as I have some design requirement in which I need to access container managed resources in a standard pojo.

This is what am doing and just wanted to see your opinion on this and if there are any side-effects of doing this.

```
1. have a @Singleton bean managed by jboss container.
    Example:
    @Singleton'
    @Startup
    public class ResourceInjector(){
    @EJB
    private DAO dao1;
    @EJB 
    private DAO dao2;
    @EJB
    private  otherStatelessEjb;

}
```

1. Make the above ResourceInjector accessible via getInstance method for calls made within the container

   Example:

   ```
    @Singleton

    @Startup

    public class ResourceInjector(){
    @EJB
    private DAO dao1;
    @EJB 
    private DAO dao2;
    @EJB
    private  otherStatelessEjb;

   private ResourceInjector INSTANCE;

   public ResourceInjector(){
     ResourceInjector.INSTANCE=this
   ```

   }

   public static ResourceInjector getInstance(){
        return  ResourceInjector .INSTANCE;
      }

   public DAO getSomeDao(){
         return reference to some managed dao 
      }

   }

Now:

```
 MyNormalPojo  pojo = new MyNormalPojo();
    pojo.setSomeDao(ResourceInjector.getInstance().getSomeDao());
```

**The main question is that the introduction of static getInstance() method on the ResourceInjector is that an issue as far as EJB spec and behaviour of EJB is concerned?**

Comment: This won't work, it's managed by the container, you can try  injection or JNDI lookup.

Comment: It does work, I have tested this in the container and it works.

Comment: You should go through documentation to understand the difference - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html